# How to make imenu jump/preview new location when switching up/down like swiper or like fzf in vim?

Tags: navigation, imenu, swiper

How can I make `imenu` (with `ivy` wrapper) act like `swiper`, that mean auto switch to location when I use arrow key( or `ivy-previous/next-line` function) and if I exit it will come back to current location?